# Verificar se as Localizações simuladas estão ativas

Tags: java, android

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que irá usar o GPS, para registrar uma rota.

Existem aplicações ( [um exemplo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.dvilleneuve.lockito) ) ,   que simulam a sua localização.

Isto é feito através de uma opção de desenvolvimento :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber se é possível saber se esta opção está ativa?

Para que caso positivo, não permita o usuário iniciar a rota.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partir da API18 a classe [Location](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/location/Location.html) disponibiliza o método [isFromMockProvider()](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/location/Location.html#isFromMockProvider%28%29) que retorna `true` se a localização tem origem no *mock provider*.

Para saber se as localizações simuladas estão activas use o *provider* [provider.Settings.Secure](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html)

```
public static boolean isMockLocationsOn(Context context) {
  // returna true se as localizações simuladas estão activas.
  if (Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
                                Settings.Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION).equals("0"))
     return false;
  else
     return true;
 }
```

<sub>[Código adaptado do SOen.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16776891/2556111)</sub>

Note que [ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION) passou a ser considerada obsoleta a partir da API23.